# EF 5 mapping relation mapping with fluent API

Tags: .net, entity-framework, fluent-interface

These are tables, the fields end with * are PK. In the **Image** table one of the **HomeID** or **CarID** must have the value and the other one is null. Similar to this in the **Feature**
they are 0 instead of null so can use it as a Key (`this.HasKey`). But When I tried to mapping the they cannot be found in the related record. For example `Home.Images` returns 0 record.

```
+---------------+ +-----------------+ +---------------+ +---------------+ +---------------+
|Home           | |Car              | |Image          | |Feature        | |FeatureType    |
|---------------| |-----------------| |---------------| |---------------| |---------------|
|HomeID*        | |CarID*           | |ImageID*       | |FeatureTypeId* | |FeatureTypeId* |
|Title          | |Brand            | |Name           | |HomeID*        | |Name           |
|Description    | |Model            | |URL            | |CarID*         | |               |
|Address        | |Year             | |HomeID(null)   | |               | |               |
|               | |                 | |CarID (null)   | |               | |               |
+---------------+ +-----------------+ +---------------+ +---------------+ +---------------+
```

These are the codes for my models and mapping.

```
    public class BaseModel
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets Id
        /// </summary>
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }

    public class Home : BaseModel
    {
        /*All direct fields*/

        public List<Image> Images{get; set;}
    }

    internal class HomeMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Home>
    {
        public HomeMap()
        {
            /* All direct mapping to Properties to ColumnsNames */

            // I tried the following 2 lines 

            //this.HasOptional(p => p.Images).WithRequired().WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
            //this.HasOptional(p => p.Images).WithMany().Map(m => m.MapKey("ImageId")).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        }
     }

    /* All the same definition and mapping for the others*/
    /* ImageMap for the relation*/
    /* Image model has a field type `Home` name **Home** */

    internal class ImageMap: EntityTypeConfiguration<Image>
    {
        public ImageMap()
        {
            /* All direct mapping to Properties to ColumnsNames */
            //Currently this is what I am using for the mapping
            this.HasOptional(i => i.Home).WithMany(h => h.Images).HasForeignKey(i => i.HomeID).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        }
     }
```